# Visual Studio 2013 Designer View not showing the UI Elements

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I started facing the weird problem recently on my new laptop.

I installed a fresh copy of Windows 8.1 and then Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

It worked fine for the first few hours, but the next time I opened it, it did not show the UI elements in the XAML Designer view. There's no error, the XAML code is perfectly alright and then on hovering over the supposed-to-be-visible elements, their outline is visible as well as selectable.

Surprisingly this is the case only with all new Windows Store Projects I open or create. The Windows Phone App Designer View works perfectly fine.

I reinstalled Visual Studio a couple of times and at last even formatted the OS and reinstalled it, but the problem still persists.

Comment: try the Update 2 RC: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307

Comment: What kind of controls are they? UserControls? Templated? Custom? Build-in? Also, have you tried Rebuilding?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yeah Ok!! Gonna do that soon. But I dont think that'll help!

Comment: @NateDiamond Yeah, usercontrols, stackpanels, grids, everything. And rebuilding doesnt help at all as it is not a prob with a particular project but it is with the installed components.

Comment: I have had a few problems with my xaml designer in vs 2013. I had to right click the file and go to "Open With..." and change the default to the XAML Designer. Check what yours is set to.

Comment: @Daisy Yes, I checked. Its XAML UI Designer but it still doesnt work, even after reinstalling and updating the whole thing!!

Comment: @VarunMashru did you solve this issue?

Comment: @JTIM: Yeah! Check out his thread. This is the bug-report I raised on the Microsoft VS Forum regarding the same issue. Refer to my last update(that's the solution!) https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/870242/visual-studio-2013-ultimate-designer-not-showing-any-ui-elements-controls

Comment: @VarunMashru, Thx! Put it in a answer below and I'll vote it up! Such that people easily can find the answer on stack :)

Answer (score 3):

@JTIM: Sure!!

### **Posted by Varun Mashru on 5/23/2014 at 3:54 AM on Visual Studio Feedback Forum**

> Surprisingly and fortunately, I found the solution just two days ago.
>   It bit of a bummer but that's what it is.
>
> Its nothing to do with the VS setup or the OS.
>
> The first thing to notice here is that it happens with notebooks only.
>   The REASON??
>
> Because notebooks do not have completely dedicated GPUs. These GPUs
>   act as secondary processors for the onboard graphics solution which is
>   directly connected to the display. Hence they fire up only when
>   needed.
>
> My notebook Dell Inspiron 15 3537 -- Core i5 4200U (Intel HD Graphics
>   4400 onboard) + AMD Radeon HD 8670M has got a switchable graphics
>   solution. Hence the software chooses as to which GPU does the
>   weight-lifting.
>
> The power settings when cranked up to the max indicate that the AMD
>   GPU must be the one that should take the lead.
>
> And in the case of VS it does not happen properly (Don't know why??).
>   Maybe the UI components cant decide that which GPU processor to choose
>   or whatever.
>
> So the simple workaround I found was to bring the graphics settings
>   down by just a notch. Which is selecting the 'Optimize Performance'
>   option in the Switchable Graphics instead of 'Maximize Performance'
>   field in the power plans.
>
> And voila, It works perfectly fine!!!!
>
> Share this with everyone who has freaked out for months on this
>   issue!! :)