# VS 2013, designer view not able to show UI elements

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have a my WPF application in VS 2010.

Now I want to migrate to VS 2013.

In one system I installed VS 2013 and tried to open my application.
While opening the solution, I got migration report
- For .csproj - there are no messages logged.
- for .sln  - The solution file does not require migration.

After this I tried to do clean build. Its completed without any build errors.
Now I tried to run my application, I was able to run it.

But when I tried to open .xaml files in VS IDE, I am not able to see any control in selected .xaml file.

I tried to search in net for the issue, I got this
[Visual Studio 2013 Designer View not showing the UI Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326966/visual-studio-2013-designer-view-not-showing-the-ui-elements)

and the this also https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/870242/visual-studio-2013-ultimate-designer-not-showing-any-ui-elements-controls

Tried to open devenv in safemode

while selecting .xaml file got this error message

```
 Package 'DesignerPackage' failed to load
```

Does anyone also faced this issue?

Comment: Faced a similar problem with Visual Studio 2013 community edition designer. For me the solution was a re-install of Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a simple project? The designer of the Visual Studio was completetly redesigned between VS2010 and VS2012, so there is a chance that the controls used in the project don't have support for the new designer.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried to check with controls and their properties,as you suggested. Now Able to see UI and all controls. Window property Visible=Collapse was set. After changes its working fine. thanks